# How to express the Parameters correctly in SQLite Select statement

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I am just not sure the correct way to express the parameters in the SQLite Select statement with parameters.

In the Select-statement , how to express?

1) use =?  or ='?'

"Is_Offline_Trans =?" or "Is_Offline-Trans='?'"

2) for Number,
Example  "0"  or "'0'"

3) For String

Example: "SQlite's Rocking solid" or "'SQLite's Rocking Solid"

```
is this correct?

here my Parameterized Select statement:
string string Company ="Anderson's Studio";


var Orders = db.Query<SalesOrderHeader >("Select * From SalesOrderHeader Where Is_SyncToNAV =?" + 
" AND Is_Offline_Trans =?" +
" AND DataEntryComplete =?" + 
" AND Company =?","0" ,"1" ,"1", Company);


Can I do hard code for the company this way:

" AND Company =?", "Anderson's Studio"
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the SQL statement, a parameter is just a single `?`.
With quotes, `'?'` would be a string containing a single question mark character.

The parameter values are not given in SQL. but come from your program.
Therefore, you must write them correctly for the programming language that you're using.
(C# does not quote numbers.)

Comment: The company name can contain a single quote or apostrophe. It comes from a database.I use string Cpy1 for company. When I use " Company ='?', Cpy1 as above in the Query statement, there is no result. When I just use company=?, Cpy1. It works. Is this correct?

Comment: Quotes matter when you write strings as literals in your source code. What works correctly is correct.